# vue custom emit doesnt work in v-for

Tags: vue.js

I have a component that looks like this:

```
<task-list :content="lesson.children" :iterator="lesson.section" :user="user" @updateTask="updateTask"></task-list>
```

I use component in 2 different pages. In on page its inserted just as is, in another page its parent is a v-for so it looks like:

```
<div class="lesson-list-item" v-bind:class="{ 'lesson-complete':  course.iterator_position > index}" v-for="(lesson, index) in content" >

   <task-list :content="lesson.children" :iterator="lesson.section" :user="user" @updateTask="updateTask"></task-list>

</div>
```

Both pages have the method:

```
updateTask(index){

                var self = this;

                this.loaded     = false;
                this.iterator   = index;
                this.newTask    = index;
                setTimeout(function() { self.loaded = true }, 10);

            }
```

This is what task-list emits on a click:

```
cardClick(index, slug, initialIterator){

                console.log(index);

                if( index <= this.initialIterator){
                  this.$emit('updateTask', index);
                }

            }
```

The page where its not wrapped in a `v-for` works, the one where it is never receives the emit event.

Comment: You might want to include the code that emits the `updateTask` event.  And either clarify what you mean by "does not work" or include a link to a jsFiddle exhibiting the problem.

Comment: @patricksteele I just updated the question

Comment: @patricksteele thanks for mentioning the updateTask emit. It wrapped in a way that will trigger on one page but not another so it makes sense. I was focused on the wrong area

Answer (score 0):

I think your component doesn't emit an `updateTask` event.

Add this to the method that you want to fire the event: `this.$emit('updateTask');`

Comment: task-list component emits the event fine but only recieved when `<task-list>` is not in a v-for. When I do have `<task-list>` by itself the `updateTask` method works fine.